# Rx: Create a subsequent observable from an observable with a different type (Chaining observers)

Tags: c#, system.reactive

We have a situation where a method call to a service returns an `IObservable<T1>` but our client expects an `IObservable<T2>`. It's trivial to convert T1 to T2.

Is there something in Rx that allows this? (i.e. chaining observers)

I know I can manually create a secondary observer and then listen to the changes of the original observer and forward them on with the new type but was wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing it?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast your `IObservable<T1>` to `IObservable<T2>` using `Select`

```
IObservable<T2> stream = service.MethodCall().Select( TrivialConversion );

private T2 TrivialConversion( T1 param )
{
    return new T2( param );
}
```